# A program is using up 150MB/s of disk usage

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I get 100% disk usage when it shows 1MB/s, but now I get over 150MB/s!
I know disk usage 100% means you have filled up your hard drive with files, will the files get deleted automatically? What if a program I'm using is filling up my hard drive with 150MB per sec? What happens if I used up 100% disk usage for a long time, does this means my hard drive's life is shorter?

About my hard drive: WD Green 1TB HDD
 201GB, 54.2GB free space on C:drive and D:drive repectively.

[image]

Comment: 100% disk usage doesn't mean your disk is full - it means it is very busy. Your program `QQ...` is doing a lot of disk read/writes.

Comment: Whom ever told you that "100% disk usage"  means you have filled up your storage device told you incorrect information.

Comment: @Ramhound https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140216145141AAutUFk (See the last comment)

Comment: @darkfang Yahoo is not a reliable source for answers to anything ...

Comment: @darkfang - The information is still not correct.  Fred from your link is 100% wrong.  Justin is closer with his "100% disk usage means that your system is low with space (memory area)"  as being the real culprit although not in your case because you have plenty of memory free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get 100% disk usage when it shows 1MB/s, but now I get over 150MB/s!

Hard disks operate using physical movements of disks and heads, and some movements faster than others. Therefore drives can be made 100% busy by doing far less of some actions than others.

> I know disk usage 100% means you have filled up your hard drive with files,

No it doesn't. 100% disk usage in Task Manager means the disk is busy doing reads or writes 100% of the time. It has nothing to do with how much space is filled.

> will the files get deleted automatically?

Files you manually create are never deleted automatically. Temporary files usually get deleted automatically.

> What if a program I'm using is filling up my hard drive with 150MB per sec?

It is not "filling" anything. If that is an antivirus program and it is *reading* at 150MB/sec, which is normal for an antivirus scan.

> What happens if I used up 100% disk usage for a long time, does this means my hard drive's life is shorter?

No. Utilization has no real effect on the life time of *hard drives*. High write utilisation does have an effect on the life time of *solid state drives* though.

Comment: High write for SSD's: Aye, maxed out writing for a decade can really harm a SSD. Though they tend to get replaced before that time anyway.

(Old, first gen SSDs did had a problem with it, newer ones not so much).

Comment: @Hennes: Newer SSDs actually have a much bigger problems with it, flash PE endurance has gone *down* 200-fold over the last decade. But even then it takes months to years to wear it out.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq The program `QQ...` is a torrent downloader (IMO sometimes works better than uTorrent), this happens quite often, 100% disk usage with more than 1MB/s. What makes the program so busy doing reads & writes?

Comment: Well it's torrenting. Therefore it will be writing to the drive.

Comment: @darkfang That is normal when downloading torrrents (if you have the wrong disk cache settings). Check the "Disk Cache" setting in your torrent program.